# Want to display JavaScript inside an input field so that I can edit it

Tags: javascript, html

Instead of the span tag where `id="second"` goes, I want an input text field where the value is displayed like it is displayed now but so that I can edit it. In other words, I want to be able to  [edit the value that shows up in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmMUE.png). How can this be done?

```
<html>
<head>

<style>
     .slider {
       writing-mode: bt-lr; /* IE */
      -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical; /* WebKit */
       width: 90px;
       height: 550px;
       padding: 0 5px;
    }
</style>

<script>
     var slider = document.getElementById("first");
     var output = document.getElementById("second");
     output.innerHTML = slider.value;

     slider.oninput = function() {
       output.innerHTML = this.value;
     }
</script>

</head>
<body>

    <input type="range" min="0" max="1500" value="0" class="slider" id="first"/>
    <p>Value(mm): <span id="second"></span></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `input` text. Also you have to use `value` instead of `innerHTML`:

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("first");
var output = document.getElementById("second");
output.value = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.value = this.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="1500" value="0" class="slider" id="first"/>

<p>Value(mm): <input type="text" id="second" /></p>
```